# Cannot use .AddDefaultTokenProviders() and .AddIdentity() n .net 8

Tags: c#, .net

We are currently updating our projects to .NET 8, but there are a few issues that we are running into that seems to be undocummented on the official documentation.

The first problem comes from moving from this:

```
        services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CustomDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

to this:

```
        services.AddIdentityCore<CustomUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CustomDbContext>();
```

1. The `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()` is not available to the second version - not sure why. Both extension methods are returning `IdentityBuilder` and `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()` is an extension of exactly `IdentityBuilder`.
2. The reason I am moving to the second version is because the `AddIdentity` extension is no longer available - not sure why again. I was trying to make it work but saw that multiple people, including demos from Microsoft, are using the `AddIdentityCore` version. What is also confusing is that people are saying that the `AddIdentity` extension comes from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, which is deprecated, but I didn't had that imported on the .NET 6 version and the project still works.

I checked multiple times the imported NuGet packages and everything needed seems there;

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

I see people are suggestion `.AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<CustomerUser>>(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider);` but again, `DataProtectorTokenProvider` reference cannot be resolved.

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between the two and how can I make it work? And also, if `AddIdentity` comes from the depraceted `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, why are people still suggesitng/using this in .NET 6/7/8 code examples?

Thanks!

I tried importing ``Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core`, but that didn't help.

Also read through the Microsoft's documentation on tha matter - nothing.